# Trouble concatenating data.table results from within a foreach loop in R

Tags: r, loops, foreach, data.table

I am working with data.table objects within nested foreach loops and I am having trouble creating the results object the way I would prefer.

Basically the idea is to generate the length(intersect(set1, set2)). I also want to generate length(union(set1, set2)) and a couple of other metrics.

Code below with sample data:

```
library(iterators)
library(data.table)
library(foreach)

#generate dummy data
set.seed(1212)
sample1 <- data.frame(parentid=round((runif(50000, min=1, max=50000))), childid=round(runif(100000, min=1, max=100000)))
length(unique(sample1$parentid))

#get unique parents
sample1uniq <- as.data.frame(unique(sample1$parentid))
names(sample1uniq) <- "parentid"

#convert original dataset to data.table
sample1 <- data.table(sample1)
setkey(sample1,parentid)

#convert unique ids to data.table
sample1uniq <- data.table(sample1uniq)
setkey(sample1uniq,parentid)

#a random sample of 5K to users to scan against
sample2uniq_idx <- sample(1:nrow(sample1uniq), size=5000)
sample2uniq <- sample1uniq[sample2uniq_idx]
sample2uniq <- data.table(sample2uniq)
setkey(sample2uniq,parentid)

#construct iterators
sample1uniq_iter <- iter(sample1uniq)
sample2uniq_iter <- iter(sample2uniq)
```

EDIT 12/5/2013 to make my question clearer:

```
outerresults <- foreach (x = sample1uniq_iter, .combine=rbind, .packages=c('foreach','doParallel', 'data.table')) %dopar% {
  b <- sample1[J(x)]                          #ith parent
  b2 <- as.data.frame(b)[,2]  #ith parent's children

  foreach (y = sample2uniq_iter, .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
    c <- sample1[J(y)]                          #jth parent
    c2 <- as.data.frame(c)[,2]  #jth parent's children

    common <- length(intersect(b2, c2))

    results <- list(u1=x, u2=y, inter=common)        
  }  
}
```

I was expecting the results to come out like this (made up):

```
u1 u2 inter
1  2  10
1  3  4
1  4  7
1  5  6
2  3  10
2  4  4
3  5  7
4  5  6
```

Instead it comes out as a list where u1 & u2 as first 2 elements & inter as SUM(length(intersect(set1, set2))).

Thanks for any ideas...

Comment: it's not altogether clear what you are trying to calculate.  The output of `merge(..)` is a data.table, so you can daisychain `[` after it, ie:  `merge(..)[, list(intersect=.N, union=length(unique(childid)))]` etc.

Comment: I may not fully understand your example, but if the output from each iteration is to be a `data.table`, then I think you need to change your `.combine` to `c` (the default which will return results in a list) and use `rbindList` on the result to `rbind` all the data.tables in the list together.

Comment: @SimonO101: I changed the question now, hopefully it's clearer now. Appreciate your help.

Comment: A quick note for anyone searching this topic.  From the `foreach` description:  The `%:%` operator is the nesting operator, used for creating nested `foreach` loops. Type `vignette("nested")` at the R prompt for more details.

Answer (score 3):

## A Solution

Your primary problem is with the iterators. Keep in mind that data tables are treated as lists by many things (such as iterators), so the two iterators you generated will each iterate over exactly one item, the single column in each of the data tables.  If you look closely at your result:

```
> str(outerresults)
List of 3
 $ u1   : num [1:31602] 2 3 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 14 ...
 $ u2   : num [1:5000] 14 26 27 31 34 61 68 81 99 106 ...
 $ inter: int 14778
```

u1 is basically just `sample1unique`, u2 is `sample2unique`, and inter is:

```
> length(intersect(sample1[J(sample1uniq)][,childid], sample1[J(sample2uniq)][,childid]))
[1] 14778
```

In other words, you didn't actually loop through anything at all.

The other problem you have is that this approach (once fixed for the above issue) is very slow.  You are growing a very large object by rbinding lists approximately 160MM times.  This is bad news.  I fixed it (changed iterators) and ran it with much smaller size to give you an idea (100 x 20, or 1/8000 of the original size):

```
#generate dummy data
set.seed(1212)
sample1 <- data.frame(parentid=round((runif(50, min=1, max=50))), childid=round(runif(100, min=1, max=100)))
length(unique(sample1$parentid))

#get unique parents
sample1uniq <- as.data.frame(unique(sample1$parentid))
names(sample1uniq) <- "parentid"

#convert original dataset to data.table
sample1 <- data.table(sample1)
setkey(sample1,parentid)

#convert unique ids to data.table
sample1uniq <- data.table(sample1uniq)
setkey(sample1uniq,parentid)

#a random sample of 5K to users to scan against
sample2uniq_idx <- sample(1:nrow(sample1uniq), size=20)
sample2uniq <- sample1uniq[sample2uniq_idx]
sample2uniq <- data.table(sample2uniq)
setkey(sample2uniq,parentid)

# Notice how we don't use iterator objects

outerresults <- foreach (x = sample1uniq$parentid, .combine=rbind, .packages=c('foreach','doParallel', 'data.table')) %dopar% {
  b <- sample1[J(x)]                          #ith parent
  b2 <- as.data.frame(b)[,2]  #ith parent's children

  results <- foreach (y = sample2uniq$parentid, .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
    c <- sample1[J(y)]                          #jth parent
    c2 <- as.data.frame(c)[,2]  #jth parent's children

    common <- length(intersect(b2, c2))

    results <- list(u1=x, u2=y, inter=common)
    results
  }
}
#  user  system elapsed 
#  1.57    0.00    1.60 
head(outerresults)
#         u1 u2 inter
# result.1 2  2  4    
# result.2 2  4  0    
# result.3 2  7  0    
# result.4 2  7  0    
# result.5 2  8  2    
# result.6 2  8  2
```

At full size would have taken over 3 hours, assuming everything scales properly.

## An Optimization

I think you're better off foregoing the loops altogether and using `data.table` all around:

```
# Prepare data in two data tables

vec.samp1 <- par.ids             # exact copy of what we generated earlier
vec.samp1.child <- child.ids     # exact copy of what we generated earlier
dt.s1 <- data.table(sample1=vec.samp1, sample1.child=vec.samp1.child, key="sample1")

vec.samp2 <- sample2.ids         # exact copy of what we generated earlier
dt.s2 <- dt.s1[data.table(sample2=vec.samp2)]
setnames(dt.s2, c("sample2", "sample2.child"))

# Create the cartesian join of our data sets and then
# join to get the child values

combinations <- CJ(sample1=vec.samp1, sample2=vec.samp2)
setkey(combinations, "sample1")
combinations <- combinations[dt.s1, allow.cartesian=T]
setkey(combinations, "sample2")
combinations <- combinations[dt.s2, allow.cartesian=T]

# Compute intersect and union

combinations[order(sample1, sample2), 
  list(
    intersect=length(intersect(sample1.child, sample2.child)),
    union=length(union(sample1.child, sample2.child))
  ),
  by=list(sample1, sample2)
]
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.06    0.00    0.06 

#    sample1 sample2 intersect union
# 1:       2       2         4     4
# 2:       2       4         0     6
# 3:       2       7         0    10
# 4:       2       8         2    10
# 5:       2       9         0     6
```

Same results, but 25x faster (though note that the data.table version only reports unique combinations of sample1-sample2).

Comment: Thanks @BrodieG, but I am not sure catesian-joining a 40M dataset to itself will work for me. Plus forgoing the parallelized loops means I am not exploiting the parallel nature of the problem.

Comment: I believe your loop is equivalent to a cartesian join.  Parallelization is an issue, but there are probably ways to break the problem down and handle each as data.table problem.

Comment: Also, aside from the different implementation, I do believe I answered your original question explaining why your implementation did not work as expected.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes, that you did, I'm sorry if I didn't give you due credit for that. Thanks again.

Comment: Would you mind checking the question as answered then?  Thanks.